# Azure Image Build - azure-arm: failed to delete the managed image

Tags: azure, azure-devops, packer

Hi I'm trying to update Linux VM Image which is currently running on VMss.
[image]

while running above task, I'm getting following error.

```
-> azure-arm: failed to delete the managed image named xxxxxx  OperationNotAllowed : Operation 'Image Delete' is not allowed since the Virtual Machine ScaleSet xxxxx is currently using the Image xxxxx
```